# two values in single array combine from json

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a trip name and id is getting seperately from Json I want to add those in single array arrayName is tripdet;

I want to show both values in listview like

```
Mytrip     55
-------------
secondtrip 56
-------------
Thirdtrip  57
-------------
Fourthtrip 58
-------------
Fifthtrip  59
```

I have tried it in bellow coding but not able to do it, need some one help.

```
    ArrayList<String> tr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> tr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> tripdet = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            System.out.println("--RESULT--" + result);
            JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                JSONArray  jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    jObject= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String tripname = jObject.getString("Tripname");
                    String tripid = jObject.getString("id");
                    //Log.v("result1", jObject.toString());
                    Log.v("Response", tripname + " " + tripid);
                    tr1.add(tripname);  //Tripname = Mytrip
                    tr2.add(tripid);    //tripid = 55
                //Need the above two value in tripdet array


                }
```

Comment: What you need is to create a class Trip with a name and an ID, and create a list of that class.

Comment: What format should the item from `tripdet` have? How do you want these values added in the `tridet` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as JSON return always String you can concatenation both of them using + sign 
with delimiter separate them 
as following

```
ArrayList<String> tr3 = new ArrayList<String>();
 tr3.add(tripname + "|" + tripid );
```

now **tre3** contain all values of json in single **arrayList**

hint :- if you need now get each of them separately you can use method `split()` with specified delimiter you choose in my case

```
String [] data =`tre3[i].splite("|");`
```

Comment: If i want to send the id value to another activity when i tap the particular cell means how to do it.

Comment: absolutely you'll know the index clicked 
let's say you clicked on the second item this mean index one
so you can say 
String [] data =`tre3[i].splite("|");`

then data[0] contain name and data [1] contain your id 
now you can send it where you need

Comment: then String [] data has tripname or trip id? I required only trip id only

Comment: Ok got it, Will check

Comment: in this case String [] data have both of them 
another way to get id only is to use the following steps:-
1- get index of delimiter using `tre3[i].indexOf(word)`
2- use `substring(int beginIndex)` to get id only

Comment: if need help I'm here ^_^

Comment: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                    
                        String [] data =tr3[id].splite("|");

Comment: Error : Array type expected found:java.util.arraylist<java.lang.string>

Comment: I am using the id in the above method getting the error     ===in here tr3[id].

Comment: you need to make sure that **tre3** not empty
one minute i write sample for you

Comment: Try to use this 
        `String[] tre3 = {"ali|43", "ahmed|42", "danial|55"};`
        `int a = tre3[2].indexOf("|");`
        `if (a != -1) {`
            String id = tre3[2].substring(a + 1);`
         `   System.out.println(id);`
        `}`

Comment: What i am triying to say is tre3[] array has some set of values, to fetch those values I am using  tre3[0] or tre3[1] or tre3[2] then it says ---Error : Array type expected found:java.util.arraylist<java.lang.string>

Comment: that is because i used array in my example if you need in ArrayList you can use this        ` int a = tre3.get(2).indexOf("|");
        if (a != -1) {
            String id = tre3.get(2).substring(a + 1);
        }`

and you can replace number 0 , 1 and 2 with id you get

Comment: waiting your answer ^^

Comment: Ya when i mention static like tre3.get(1) i am getting the id but when i change like tre3.get(1)      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {  =====>putting long id getting error

Comment: that is because get() method need an **integer** parameter not **long** >> try to cast it to int as following 
`
        long r = 2;
        int a = tre3.get((int)r).indexOf("|");`

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working fine, I got id value because of your help and support.. many thanks